# std::shared_ptr constructor vs std::make_shared? What is better?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

Often i used `std::shared_ptr<T>::shared_ptr()` constructor.

But few days ago, i saw some text which is speaking like this.

**"You need to use std::make_shared function instead of std::shared_ptr constructor"**

What is diffrent these methods? What is better more?

Thanks to advance.

**==EDIT==**

I'm sorry. this question already exist.

Comment: Don't be sorry. Stack Overflow search doesn't always work that well. I use Google to search for duplicates :-P